# Querying nested document Elasticsearch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am learning Elasticsearch so I am not sure if this query is correct. I have checked that the data is indexed, but I don't get any hits. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this get a hit on a car where the creator's name is steve?

```
builder
.startObject()
    .startObject("car")
        .field("type", "nested")
        .startObject("properties")
            .startObject("creators")
                .field("type", "nested")                    
            .endObject()                
        .endObject()
    .endObject()
.endObject();


{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "car.creators.name": "Steve"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, in order to search nested fields you need to use [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/):

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/test
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_shards": 1,
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
            "car": {
                "properties": {
                    "creators" : {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {"type":"string"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/car/1 -d '{
    "creators": {
        "name": "Steve"
    }
}
'
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'
echo
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/test/car/_search?pretty' -d '    {
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "creators",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "creators.name": "Steve"
                        }
                    }],
                    "must_not": [],
                    "should": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [],
    "facets": {}
}
'
```

If `car.creators.name` was indexed using standard analyzer then `{"term": {"creators.name": "Steve"}}` will not find anything because word `Steve` was indexed as `steve` and the [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/) doesn't performs analysis. So, it might be better to replace it with the [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/) `{"match": {"creators.name": "Steve"}}`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to move the path field out of the query object though and insert "creators" in the path and only use creators.name in the term. Does that sound wrong or is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Path should be on the same level as query and should contain "car.creators". I have updated the example. Not sure about creators.name in the term. Is car a type in your case?

Comment: Yes, car is a type? Since I am learning about Elasticsearch would you mind explaining why I don't need it and you manage to get it working with it?

Comment: I was just confused. When I saw `"type": "nested"` under `car` I thought `car` is a field. If `car` is a type, you don't need `"type": "nested"` there and yes you need to use `creators.name` in query. I modified my example to use car as a type.

Comment: Type is optional in the "path" element. It can be there but because I already specified type on url it's unnecessary. Type shouldn't be present in the nested query.